# Groovy code not accessible inside AngularJs component

Tags: angularjs, grails

I have some groovy code inside my AngularJs 1.5 component's template. As you might know,the component template property does not allow us to add any file except HTML file(or does it?),whereas the groovy code will not execute inside a HTML file. Is there any way to do this?

FYI, I have already tried using component transclusion but it does not serve the purpose well as it creates numerous child scopes(as I need multi-slot transclusion). When I need to access my controller(which I need to do very often) from inside the transcluded element the only possible way I came across was using the required numbers of $parent, which does not look great at all.

Answer (score 0):

> whereas the groovy code will not execute inside a HTML file. Is there
>   any way to do this?

Not really, no.  In theory it could be done, but someone would have to build a technology to support that.